# Incorrect syntax near '.' while using Coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, coalesce

I am trying to join three tables, I joined two successfully.

This Worked (Two Tables)

```
SELECT  ImportExportBadFile.ID, ImportExportSettingID,
    ImportExportBadFile.UserID,
    Coalesce(UserName,'') UserName  
    FROM
    ImportExportBadFile 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Users HGSQLUsers ON ImportExportBadFile.UserID = HGSQLUsers.ID
    ORDER BY  ImportExportBadFile.DateTimeStamp DESC
```

- UserName belongs to Users Table

Now, when I tried to add another Table:

```
SELECT  ImportExportBadFile.ID, ImportExportSettingID,
    SETT.Name,
    ImportExportBadFile.UserID,
    Coalesce(UserName,'') HGSQLUsers.UserName  
    FROM
    ImportExportBadFile 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Users HGSQLUsers ON ImportExportBadFile.UserID = HGSQLUsers.ID
    INNER JOIN ImportExportSettings SETT ON ImportExportBadFile.ImportExportSettingID = SETT.ID  
    ORDER BY  ImportExportBadFile.DateTimeStamp DESC
```

> It gives Error : "Incorrect syntax near '.'." at line :
>   "Coalesce(UserName,'') HGSQLUsers.UserName"

If I write only `UserName` It gives

> "Ambiguous column name 'UserName'."

Help.

Comment: Remove `HGSQLUsers`.

Comment: from whole query? or only from "HGSQLUsers.UserName"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `UserName` column exists in both tables, you need to specify from which table do want to take `UserName` as below

```
SELECT  ImportExportBadFile.ID, ImportExportSettingID,
    SETT.Name,
    ImportExportBadFile.UserID,
    Coalesce( HGSQLUsers.UserName  ,'') as "HGSQLUsers.UserName"
    FROM
    ImportExportBadFile 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Users HGSQLUsers ON ImportExportBadFile.UserID = HGSQLUsers.ID
    INNER JOIN ImportExportSettings SETT ON ImportExportBadFile.ImportExportSettingID = SETT.ID
ORDER BY  ImportExportBadFile.DateTimeStamp DESC
```

Error `"Incorrect syntax near '.'." at line :` comes from alias `HGSQLUsers.UserName` you can use it but in quotas.

I also recommend you to use aliases for every table as below - is more readable for me

```
SELECT  I.ID, I.ImportExportSettingID,
        SETT.Name,
        I.UserID,
       Coalesce( HGSQLUsers .UserName  ,'') as "HGSQLUsers.UserName"
FROM ImportExportBadFile I
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users HGSQLUsers ON I.UserID = HGSQLUsers.ID
INNER JOIN ImportExportSettings SETT ON I.ImportExportSettingID = SETT.ID  
ORDER BY  I.DateTimeStamp DESC
```

Comment: @SurajS I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to accept one of the answer to close to question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this worked for me in trial and error:

```
SELECT  ImportExportBadFile.ID, ImportExportSettingID,
    SETT.Name,
    ImportExportBadFile.UserID,
    Coalesce(HGSQLUsers.UserName,'')
    FROM
    ImportExportBadFile 
    INNER JOIN ImportExportSettings SETT ON ImportExportBadFile.ImportExportSettingID = SETT.ID  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Users HGSQLUsers ON ImportExportBadFile.UserID = HGSQLUsers.ID
    ORDER BY  ImportExportBadFile.DateTimeStamp DESC
```

but @Parado's Answer is more specific and explaining.

Thank you.